# Fire form change event from any input (only once)

Tags: jquery, input, onchange

Hi suppose there's a simple general form.

```
<form id="first_form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Now basically, I want to know whether user started editing the form starting from any input. So only need to trigger change event **once**. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with setting a variable globally, I used `formState` which is outside the on change function.

Find all the inputs inside `#first_form` and if one of them is modified, change the variable value and use it for condition.

```js
var formState = 0;

$("#first_form").find("input").on("change", function() {

  if (formState) {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    alert("Edited first time");
    $("p").html("State: Edited");

    // Trigger events here
  }

  // Change state
  formState = 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>State: Unedited</p>

<form id="first_form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Tks Jerdine this is what I wanted. Simple & elegant

Answer (score 1):

Bind the same chagne event to each object, and unbind all change events once triggered.

```
$("#first_name, #last_name, #email, #password").one("change", function(){
    console.log("you changed.")
    $("#first_name, #last_name, #email, #password").off("change");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#first_name").on("change", function(){
        console.log("first_name on change called");
    })
$("#first_form").on("change", function(){
        console.log("first_form on change called");
        $("p").html("State: Edited");
        $("#first_form").off("change");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>State: Unedited</p>

<form id="first_form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Had no idea about **off**. Useful but if I need to fire different change event for any input, it will be prevented from this. Tks

Comment: Change event on a child element will be still on.. updated the sinppt.. `$("#first_name").on("change", function(){
        console.log("first_name on change called");
    })`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onfocus` or `onchange` event on inputs like :

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
   //Do Somethig
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
   //Do Somethig
});
```

This will event will fire when the user puts the mouse' cursor inside your input.